# URL Rewriting anchor

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to pass a value to other page with URL Rewriting.

I have 2 pages. 1 is index.php and 2 is videoplayer.php.

inside index.php. there's

```
<div class="film">
<figure>
<img src="film-ghost-shell-2017.jpg" width="135px" height="200px" alt="">
<figcaption><a href="http://127.0.0.1/Ghost-In-The-Shell-2017/"><p title="Ghost In The Shell (2017)">Ghost In The Shell (2017)</p></a></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

How can i pass the value anchor when i clicked Ghost-In-The-Shell-2017 to videoplayer.php without changing the name in url like still http://127.0.0.1/ghost-in-the-shell-2017/?

videoplayerphp. i still don;t know how to pass anchor value to videoplayer but form it possible.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @Scuzzy 1. when user clicked everything inside element div. it will pass a value  movie title to videoplayer.php. 
2. it rewrite videplayer.php to http://127.0.0.1/movie title.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a querystring or a form submission, the only other alternatives are using a cookie or local storage. Here's a simple solution using a cookie.

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/Ghost-In-The-Shell-2017/" onclick="document.cookie='Ghost-In-The-Shell-2017'">
```

Then on the other page you can grab the value that was stored in the cookie,

```
let video;
video = document.cookie;
```

Comment: The problem is when i press that anchor it show page not found. cause that page not exist. the page is videoplayer.php

Answer (score 0):

You looking for web servers rewrite rules. If you are using Apache research the topic `Apache mod-rewrite` or if you using NGINX `nginx rewrite rules`. Another common term for this functionality is `pretty URls`.

Comment: i try to write .htaccess in root. but my video.php not show all RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/$ video.php [NC,L]

Comment: @user9189025 Make sure that you are passing what you are capturing in regex to the new script `video.php`. Ex: `video.php?title=$1`